# Need help working with comaddins.connect

Tags: powershell, outlook-addin

I have created a script that will activate an Outlook Add-in if it is not currently active in the ribbon. This is done by changing the boolean setting on comaddin.connect from false to true. The script only works under certain conditions.

Basically, the issue I've come across is that when you run new-object -comobject Outlook.Application, it will only work if the shell is open in the same mode as Outlook (if Outlook is currently open, which it needs to be). Since the add-in was installed to all users, the boolean setting I need to change is in HKLM which requires the powershell window to be ran in administrator mode. So, I can't work with the Outlook comobject if the shell is in administrator mode, but I can't change the setting I need unless the shell IS in administrator mode.

Note: The below code works if Outlook and the shell are both ran in administrator mode, or if the add-in is uninstalled and reinstalled under the current user only. It doesn't work with the add-in installed to all users, which is what we need unfortunately.

I'm hoping someone out there has a creative way around this! :)

```
$objoutlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$objoutlook.application.COMAddIns | where {$_.description -eq "Addin Name Here"} | %{$_.connect=$true}
```

Comment: Deploy two different scripts then?

Comment: Change permissions on the target registry key?

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing you can do about that, it's a catch-22. the real solution would be for the COM addin itself to hide or show its UI appropriately while staying active at all times.

Comment: @kath - that **is** the answer even if you don't like it: COM addin should have the logic or an API to turn its UI on or off. That logic does not belong in an external application. Just best practice.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Dmitry! The cause of the issue is that once in a while at random when Office 2016 updates, certain addins may start slow the next time Outlook starts and this will cause a prompt for the user asking if they want to disable slow addins. Not really knowing what they are seeing, they just click yes or ok to get through it, and this causes the boolean setting to change to false. The addin would not know this wasn't a purposeful action by the user, and this behavior is actually controlled by Outlook. Unfortunately, no solution exists down the addin avenue either.